# Programmatically expand all notifications or one package notification

Tags: android

I searched over the net how to expand the notification bar, found some answers for different API but all of them used the line `Object service = getSystemService( "statusbar" );` , when I type this line it gives me errors under the "statusbar" expression , here is my code :

```
 try{
            Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
            Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
            Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
            expand.invoke(service);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        }
```

Here is the full error:

```
Must be one of: Context.POWER_SERVICE,
Context.WINDOW_SERVICE, 
Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, 
Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE,
Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE, 
Context.ALARM_SERVICE, 
Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, 
Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE, 
Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE, 
Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE, 
Context.LOCATION_SERVICE, 
Context.SEARCH_SERVICE, 
Context.SENSOR_SERVICE, 
Context.STORAGE_SERVICE, 
Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE, 
Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE, 
Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE, 
Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE, 
Context.WIFI_SERVICE, 
Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE, 
Context.NSD_SERVICE, 
Context.AUDIO_SERVICE, 
Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE, 
Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE, 
Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE, 
Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE, 
Context.CARRIER_CONFIG_SERVICE, 
Context.TELECOM_SERVICE, 
Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE, 
Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE, 
Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE, 
Context.APPWIDGET_SERVICE, 
Context.DROPBOX_SERVICE, 
Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE, 
Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE, 
Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE,
Context.NFC_SERVICE, 
Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE, 
Context.USB_SERVICE,
Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE, 
Context.INPUT_SERVICE, 
Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE,
Context.USER_SERVICE, 
Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE, 
Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE,
Context.CAMERA_SERVICE, 
Context.PRINT_SERVICE, 
Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE, 
Context.TV_INPUT_SERVICE, 
Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE, 
Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE, 
Context.BATTERY_SERVICE, 
Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE, 
Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE, 
Context.MIDI_SERVICE less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

And after this error when showing more:

This inspection looks at Android API calls and ensures that the correct type of resource is passed to an int-parameter expecting resources of a given type; it checks that APIs which expect an RGB color integer are passed actual colors rather than color resources; it checks that APIs which require a certain permission have the permission declared in the manifest; it checks that parameters expected to fall within a given range actually do; it checks that results of certain method calls are looked at by the caller, and so on.

My full code:

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    try{
        Object service = getSystemService("statusbar");
        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
        Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
        expand.invoke(service);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    Log.i("Package", pack);
    Log.i("Ticker", ticker);
    Log.i("Title", title);
    Log.i("Text", text);
    if ("com.whatsapp".equals(pack)) {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent("Msg");
        newIntent.putExtra("package", pack);
        newIntent.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        newIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        newIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(newIntent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i("Msg", "Notification Removed");
}
```

}

The code is a service running in background and when notification received the service get the details, I usually get '2 messages from XXX' instead of the messages so I want to expand them, and this is what happened :P I also tried to put it on the other class, the Activity itself inside the onRecieve broadcast  as I read somewhere you cannot use `getSystemService` outside an Activity but still the same.

Comment: dont use anything that is not in the SDK, if you want serious problems in the future use your code, you have been warned

Comment: @pskink So I can't expand notification bar?

Comment: i don't see such SDK API

Comment: @pskink I must have it :\ thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permission in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter.